# gstreamer hangs when displaying webcam and recording at the same time

Tags: video, gstreamer, gst-launch

I'm trying to use gst-launch to test a pipeline to display and record video from a webcam.  I'm using Windows 10 and was using gstreamer 16 but also tried gstreamer 18.5 and get the same issue:

This works fine:

gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=here.mp4 -e

as does this:

gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

and even this:

gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! tee name = t ! queue ! autovideosink t. ! queue ! autovideosink

But as soon as I try to combine the two sinks the command just hanges.  The display just freezes (immediately as far as I can tell).  --verbose option shows nothing obvious.

Any ideas anybody?

Thanks.

Andrew.

Comment: Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335294/gstreamer-transcoding-pipeline-1-source-n-sinks

Comment: Thanks.  That gave me a good pointer.  I also moved to using "mpegtsmux" which doesn't appear to have any issues with default buffer limits.